# Regular Expression Troubles

Tags: regex, string, string-parsing

Given the following type of string:

"#First Thing# #Another One##No Space# Main String #After Main# #EndString#"

I would like to come up with a regular expression that can return all the text surrounded by the # symbols as matches.  One of the things giving me grief is the fact that the # symbol is both the opening and closing delimiter.  All of my attempts at a regex have just returned the entire string.  The other issue is that it is possible for part of the string to not be surrounded by # symbols, as shown by the substring "Main String" above.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I have toyed around with Negative Look-behind assertion a bit, but haven't been able to get it to work.  There may or may not be a space in between the groups of #'s but I want to ignore them (not match against them) if there are.  The other option would be to just write a string parser routine, which would be fairly easy, but I would prefer to use a regex if possible.

Comment: Are you saying you want "First Thing# #Another One##No Space# Main String #After Main" as a match, or you want each token surrounded by #'s separately?

Comment: @eaolson: each one as a separate match

Comment: Why not just split on #, and grab by field number?

Comment: @Demosthenex- I could do something like that, but then I would have to ignore all of the split values that are empty or just have a space and it would be more difficult to differentiate between the "Main String" case and the bracketed by #s case.  I was mainly just looking to see if an elegant regex could handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit]

I think that this is what you need:

```
(?<=#)[^#]+?(?=#)
```

With input `#First Thing# #Another One##No Space# Main String #After Main#` matches:

- `First Thing`
- 
- `Another One`
- `No Space`
- `Main String`
- `After Main`

The second match is the space between `Thing#` and `#Another`.

[EDIT] To ignore space:

```
(?<=)(?!\s+)[^#]+?(?=#)
```

If you want to ignore trailing spaces:

```
(?<=)(?!\s+)[^#]+?(?=\s*#)
```

Comment: I believe I tried that, but I will give it a quick check and report back- thanks.

Comment: @dreyln - ignore the first one. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hmm... not sure what was up with the online regex tester I just tried, but the first one you posted actually doesn't work but your edit is pretty close- I think I can toy with it

Comment: @dreyln - what do you mean 'close'? Is there something it doesn't do?

Comment: @Alex Aza- it's matching the first space and putting that in a group as well

Comment: @Alex Aza- there may or may not be a space between the sets of ##, but I want to ignore them if they are there. That was why I put the #No Space# example that way.  I have updated my original question to reflect this.  Thanks

Comment: @Alex Aza- brilliant- Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

```
/((#[^#]+#)|([^#]+))/
```

Perhaps something like the above will match what you want.

This will match the space in between two hashes.  Hmm.

```
/((#[^#]+#)|([^#]*[^#\s]+[^#]*))/
```

That will get rid of the nasty space, I think.

Comment: It's close- I'm still getting a match on the first space with your second regex though

Comment: @NullRef- Yes it does.  I might end up using this one because (although I didn't make this clear in the question) it is nice to distinguish between the strings between the #s and the Main String by keeping the #s around the matches that have them.  I would give all three of you credit for the answer if I could.  Thanks.

Comment: @dreyln no worries. Just happy to help. @alex knows his stuff and deserves credit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The first and last groups should not be captured and the .*? should be **lazy**

```
(?:#)(.*?)(?:#)
```

I think this is what you really need:

```
((#[^#]+#)|([^#]*[^#\s]+[^#]*))
```

but it will not capture the `#`'s around `Main String`

Comment: Hmm... this expression will not match 'Main String' from the example, right?

Comment: Yes, that is true.  Ideally, I would like it to match "Main String" as well